# Can I write applications for the new iPod Nano 6G

Tags: ipod-nano

Is there any ability to write applications for the new iPod Nano 6th Generation, if so where can I find more information on this topic ?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, you can't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment, no one is positive, but the evidence points to no. While the os looks like iOS, there are a couple interviews that indicate that it's a cutdown version of it that's not meant to run external apps.

That doesn't mean that couldn't change before launch or after launch with a software update though.

Comment: That's unfortunate. Hopefully it will change. Thanks for the feedback. If anyone finds out otherwise please post it as an answer and I will change the accepted solution at that point in time.